# What is the term for "Government by comedians"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm doing research for a story where, before a person can run for federal public office, he or she has to have performed five hundred hours of stand up comedy.  Every year the nation's leaders have to perform, and the audience picks their leaders who've produced the best act (most social insight and most laughs generated).

To the best of my knowledge and from where I have searched the Internet, there's no existing term for 'rule by comedians'.  I hope I'm wrong.

There's *Kritarchy* for rule by judges,
*Theocracy* for rule by priests on behalf of a deity, and other examples where the ruling class forms out of one specific occupation.  I'm seeking something like this for satirists.

I've edited this question to indicate that I'm looking in this question exclusively for an existing term in current usage and not invented words nor invented terms.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63716/discussion-on-question-by-standardeyre-what-is-the-term-for-government-by-comed).

Answer (score 2):

Searching translation sites for the Greek for 'Comedian' I found what I think is the word 'geloiastikos' meaning mirth-provoking, which seems to be derived from the word for clown or buffoon. You'd need to have it checked by a Greek expert because I've found it in Greek script which I don't know well. If I'm right it might be the basis for the word 'Geloiastarchy' or 'Geloiarchy' formed on the same basis as the existing Kritarchy, Theocracy etc. But don't take either of my words for it without checking!
If you want to look yourself I suggest http://www.lexilogos.com/english/greek_ancient_dictionary.htm
but you will need some transliteration from the Greek.